# How create config file for Entity Framework CF in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-4, configuration, code-first

How create config file in Windows Forms and add connection string to Entity Framework?
I'm using Code First Approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right mouse click on your Windows Forms project -> Add new item -> Application configuration file = `App.config`. Then add a connection string to the file, for example for SQL Server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext"
         connectionString="Server=MyServer; Database=MyDatabase;
                           Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Here `MyContext` is the name of your derived context class (you can also name it differently if you pass that name into the `DbContext` constructor). `MyServer` is the location of the database server, for SQL Server Express for example it is `.\SQLEXPRESS`. And `MyDatabase` is the name of your database.